# Why is the username commonly used for user identification with OAuth2?

Tags: authentication, oauth, microservices

I want to set up a resource server and an external authentication server with oauth2, both servers with their own databases to avoid coupling.

Apart from verifying that the user is authenticated, I need to know which user is authenticated. If resource and authentication server share the same database, this is rather simple. But since this is not the case here I've been wondering how I could do that. The obvious choice, for me, would be to somehow obtain the user ID. However, Spring, for example, only returns the username when calling /oauth/check_token, also in all JWT examples that I've  seen the username is included in the payload but not the ID.

But why does everyone seem to prefer the username over an ID, when usernames have so many drawbacks (they might change, they might not be unique, ...)?

And what would be the correct solution to get the ID? Maybe token introspection or part of a JWT token?

Comment: Is your external authentication server implemented spring oauth2 authorization server?

Comment: @SAP yes all services (currently) use spring

Answer (score 1):

As you mention "authenticated" I will assume you are speaking about OpenID Connect as [OAuth 2.0 NOT an Authentication protocol](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/OAuth%202.0%20NOT%20an%20Authentication%20protocol).

The only true indication for the user id is the "sub" value which is dependent on the OpenID Connect Service Provider and which is a **locally unique** and never re-assigned identifier within the **Issuer** for the Authenticated Entity, which is intended to be consumed by the OAuth Client. Two Subject Identifier types are defined by OpenID Connect:

- public - provides the same sub (subject) value to all OAuth Clients. It is the default if the provider has no subject_types_supported element in its discovery document.
- pairwise - provides a different Sub value to each OAuth Client, so as not to enable OAuth Client to correlate the End-User's activities without permission.

The OpenID Connect Provider's OpenID Connect Discovery document *SHOULD* list its supported Subject Identifier types in the subject_types_supported element. 
If there is more than one type listed in the array, the OAuth Client MAY elect to provide its preferred identifier type using the subject_type parameter during Registration.

Sub MUST NOT exceed 255 ASCII characters in length.

Sub value is a Case-sensitive string.

So the sub value is UNIQUE only within the context of a Issuer value.